# Float.Parse 0 value

Tags: c#

Result:

0 0

0 0

-6361 0

-6384 -6672

0 0

0 -6793
...

Code:

```
 string regex = @"X:(.*?)\sY:(.*?)";
                if (File.Exists("minelist.log"))
                    File.Delete("minelist.log");

                File.Copy(war3path + "\\minelist.log", "minelist.log");
                string[] crdlist = File.ReadAllLines("minelist.log");

                for (int i = 0; i < crdlist.Length;i++)
                {
                    Match COORM = Regex.Match(crdlist[i], regex);
                    if (COORM.Success)
                    {
                        float x = 0.0f, y = 0.0f;
                        float.TryParse(COORM.Groups[1].Value, out x);
                        float.TryParse(COORM.Groups[2].Value, out y);
                        MessageBox.Show(x.ToString(), y.ToString());
                    }

                }

                if (File.Exists("minelist.log"))
                    File.Delete("minelist.log");
```

As a result, only certain values ​​are parsed. Others = 0.

[FILE](http://pastebin.com/ZCDGqA8b)

Result:
0 0
0 0
6361 0
-6384 6672
0 0
0 -6793
...

Comment: Unclear on what your actual question is

Comment: Does the input file really have all the whitespace in? It's either the filereading or the regex - try putting the file contents straight into the crdlist and try the code again to eliminate the file reading causing problems. If the problem persists it;s the regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your RegEx is not matching what you think it's matching. You could have inspected the capture groups using `MessageBox` (or by stepping over in the debugger). The problem is you you used `.*?` to capture the group of digits: any number of any character, lazily; Then in the `foreach` loop you used `TryParse()` but did not check the result! On the lines you got "0" as a result, the regex probably stopped too soon. The `TryParse()` would fail and leave your `X` and `Y` to there default values.

Complete Console example properly parsing everything:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] crdlist = {
                                    "X:-6625.5 Y:-6585.5",
                                    "X:-6601.25 Y:-6703.75",
                                    "X:-6361 Y:-6516.5",
                                    "X:-6384 Y:-6672",
                                    "X:-6400.25 Y:-6847.75",
                                    "X:-6608.75 Y:-6793",
                                    "X:-6739.75 Y:-6872",
                                    "X:-6429.25 Y:-6940",
                                    "X:-7015.5 Y:-6835.5",
                                    "X:-7117 Y:-6903",
                                    "X:-6885.5 Y:-6662.5",
                                    "X:-6861.5 Y:-6597",
                                    "X:-7006.5 Y:-6728",
                                    "X:-7009 Y:-6608.75",
                                    "X:-6924 Y:-6798",
                                    "X:-6970.25 Y:-6898.25",
                                    "X:-6495.25 Y:-6775",
                                    "X:-7112.5 Y:-6614.5",
                                    "X:-7115.25 Y:-6717.25",
                                    "X:-7113.25 Y:-6835.5",
                                    "X:-6493 Y:-6620.25"
                               };

            Regex re = new Regex(@"^\ *X\:([\-\.0-9]*)\ *Y\:([\-\.0-9]*)\ *$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            var us_EN = new CultureInfo("en-US");

            foreach(var line in crdlist)
            {
                Match m = re.Match(line);
                if (m.Success)
                {
                    String X = m.Groups[1].Value;
                    String Y = m.Groups[2].Value;

                    float fX = float.Parse(X, us_EN);
                    float fY = float.Parse(Y, us_EN);

                    Console.WriteLine("X={0}, Y={1}", fX, fY);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this regular expression pattern:

```
string regex = @"X:(-*d*.*d*)\sY:(-*d*.*d*)";
```